# Loading column information halfway stops for only one column

Tags: r

For a gaze study I'm doing I'm loading "large" .txt files into R. In most cases this goes as expected. However, in some cases, it stops importing the "Iview" column data and returns NA for every following row.

The strange thing is, that in the .txt file, there is no difference between the last row that was imported correctly and the following row.

```
  # Determine row when relevant GAZE data starts
  first.index <- grep("IviewTimestamp", readLines("example.txt"))[1]

  # Import gaze data
  G.t <- suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(read_table2(file = "example.txt"
                                                       col_names = F,
                                                       skip = first.index-1, 
                                                       progress = F)))


  G.df <- data.frame(G.t[, c(5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15)])

  colnames(G.df) <- c("Iview","OST", "GLX", "GLY", "GRX", 
                      "GRY", "DisR")
```

So to show you what happens:

[image]

As you can see, it suddenly stops importing Iview there, while the other variables are still loaded correctly.

Any idea what causes this? Here is the link to the "example.txt" file: https://wetransfer.com/download/21b96d13ce04c64c8b5652ccc8d0555520180914121457/41b3c8

For those who don't want to download the .txt file:

```
Gaze Data - IviewTimestamp 2147479211 OpenSesameTimeStamp 489482.0 
GazeLeft 720.346436728 479.952201339 GazeRight 827.973058949 
454.028017843 DistanceRight 628.052580903 DiameterLeft 3.53796282015 
DiamaterRight 3.6109109419
Gaze Data - IviewTimestamp **2147483209** OpenSesameTimeStamp 489485.0 
GazeLeft 721.273134082 478.473368041 GazeRight 828.55963406 
455.075058476 DistanceRight 627.613681923 DiameterLeft 3.53561314881 
DiamaterRight 3.60554349529
Gaze Data - IviewTimestamp 2147487207 OpenSesameTimeStamp 489490.0 
GazeLeft 723.172929117 475.651601215 GazeRight 829.518381282 
457.763442162 DistanceRight 627.118021226 DiameterLeft 3.53771978788 
DiamaterRight 3.60483212601
```

I myself added the ** ** to show you where in the file we are.

what I tried so far
- Delete all the rows which are loaded correctly and load the part that wasn't loaded succesfully before. It does after deleting the first rows.
- Adding an extra space in the .txt file between the two input rows where the NA emerges. Doesnt resolve the problem. 
- Adding specific column specifications for all the columns.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Generally is not liked to post links to download files. In the .txt what's written in the first NA cell?

Comment: @s_t i just want to share my .txt file. Whats written in the next line of the raw txt file is exactly in the same fashion as the one above and below. Check my edit